# How to access passport user from 404 & 500 response pages?

Tags: sails.js, passport.js

I'm using PassportJS authentication with Sails 0.10 and it seems as though the policy isn't executed before the responses for 403, 404, and 500 are executed. How can I access the user information, typically stored as `req.user` from those views?

Comment: Can you please explain how you integrated passport? Is it hosted somewhere so that I can see?

Comment: @YedhuKrishnan The repository is not public, unfortunately. Any specific questions related to the config/integration?

Answer (score 0):

You can access "req" and "res" from custom response function's context.

```
module.exports = function serverError (error, options) {
  var req = this.req;
  var res = this.res;
}
```

Eventually if error occurs before/during user authorization req.user will empty.

Comment: If the 404 error occurs for a controller that is defined, I'm able to access the req.user object. If not, it seems like passport isn't executed.

Comment: There is a catch all policy defined, too: `'*':['passport','authenticated','refreshSessionCookie']`

Comment: It looks reasonable: if there is no method in controller it is not matching any policy, even '*'. So you can call passport.authenticate() in "notFound" custom response.